# Triangle groups - uniqueness and trace field

Tags: fuchsian-groups, gr.group-theory

Dear all,

again I need your help for the following two questions: Suppose we have a triangle group of signature (p,q,\infty).

1) When is such a group unique (up to isomorphism)?
2) Do you have a method how to calculate the trace field of such a group? Is the trace field unique?

Thank you very much for your answer
Ali

Comment: I don't think I understand your question about 'unique' - of course there's only one triangle group with a give signature, because it's well defined!  Or are you worried that the signature isn't unique?  It's clear that $\Delta(p,q,\infty)\cong\Delta(p',q',\infty)$ if and only if $\lbrace p,q\rbrace=\lbrace p',q'\rbrace$ because the only torsion in $\Delta(p,q,\infty)$ is $p$-torsion and $q$-torsion.  In other words, the signature is unique.

Comment: Just to be clear, what I said above is only literally true of the orientation-preserving index-two subgroup of the triangle group (what Wikipedia calls `von Dyck groups').  But the same sort of thing applies for triangle groups.

Comment: Is it possible that the uniqueness statement in question is (or should be) that the set of Fuchsian groups isomorphic to a given triangle group forms a single $\mathbb{SL}_2(\mathbb{R})$-conjugacy class?

Comment: I do not think the question is clear enough. Should be revised or closed.  

Comment: Pete - good guess!  Although, if so, why 'up to isomorphism'?

Comment: @Henry: It is part of my guess that the "up to isomorphism" part of the question is a misstatement.  Of course I don't know for sure what the OP means, but I have studied triangle groups and this is the one true, nontrivial statement that lives in a small neighborhood of the OP's question, so far as I know.  (Note also that you want uniqueness up to conjugacy, not just abstract isomorphism, in order for the trace field to be well-defined.)

Comment: My immediate reading was: is the triangle group $(p,q,\infty)$ ever isomorphic to $(p',q',\infty)$ (changing $p$ and $q$)?  But the second question suggest something more like Pete Clark's answer.

Comment: You don't necessarily need something to be unique up to conjugacy for the trace field to be well-defined, just up to commensurability (in the wide sense). But I think the correct answer to Q1 is just: "Always, because a signature defines a group in terms of its presentation" (as explained in the selected answer below). As for Q2, nobody addressed whether there's an algorithm for computing the invariant trace field of this group, but it seems you could start with the information in the answer below, then try to compute it just by its definition.  I expect it would help to consider the geometry.

Answer (score 10):

One page 159 of *The Arithmetic of Hyperbolic Manifolds* by Maclachlan and Reid:-

> In more detail, suppose that $\Gamma$ is a $(l,m,n)$-triangle group where $1/l+1/m+1/n<1$ so that $\Gamma$ has the presentation
>
> $\langle x,y\mid x^l=y^m=(xy)^n=1 \rangle$.
>
> Then $\mathbb{Q}(\mathrm{tr}\Gamma)=\mathbb{Q}(\cos\pi/l,\cos\pi/m,\cos\pi/n)$ (see (3.25)), and the invariant trace field is a subfield of this totally real number field (see Exercise 4.9, No. 1).

More generally, Maclachlan and Reid should have the answers to all your questions about trace fields.

Comment: Although HJRW's answer uses the notation for a co-compact triangle group, non co-compact triangle groups of the form $(p,q, \infty)$ (and $(p, \infty, \infty)$ also apply here. The necessary adjustments are removing the relation $(xy)^n$ (and $y^m$) and $\mathbb{Q}(tr \Gamma) = \mathbb{Q}(cos \pi/l, cos \pi/m)$ (and $\mathbb{Q}(tr \Gamma) = \mathbb{Q}(cos \pi/l$)).